# Touchmove with preventDefault() Not Disabling Body from Scrolling on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, preventdefault, touchmove

What would be causing the script below to not prevent the `body` from scrolling on iOS when prompted on click? Is there something I've missed, in terms of implementing this?

NOTE: This is not a working snippet, just condensed examples of the script and some CSS styles:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.open").click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
    $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
  $("a.close").on("click", function(s) {
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    $('body').unbind('touchmove');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
  height: auto !important;
}
```